# Java can't find file after I've exported as a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, export

In order to load up a world in my game, my program reads off of a text file. Everything works fine in Eclipse but after exporting as a runnable jar, it can no longer find the text file.

This calls the function to read from the text file.

```
LevelHandler.loadLevel("res/levels/level.txt");
```

and this is the function itself

```
    public static void loadLevel(String file){
    String level = LevelLoader.loadFileAsString(file);
```

and this is the loadFileAsString() function

```
public static String loadFileAsString(String file){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Also, its probably worth noting that the res folder never appears in the jar but the levels folder inside does. Maybe that is what is making the file not able to be found. I  tried exporting with this but the same error came up.

```
LevelHandler.loadLevel("levels/level.txt");
```

Comment: Unless you specify a full path, then java is trying to read the file relative to the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` location

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis How should I do specify it so that the program can run on any computer?

Comment: Well, you would have to always read and write the level files from some known location. You could base it off of a directory you create in  System.getProperty("user.home").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the file system for something inside your exported jar.

If the `levels` folder is in the exported jar file, you should use `getResourceAsStream` provided by `Class` or `ClassLoader` to read them.

For example:

```
InputStream in = LevelLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/levels/level.txt");
```

Then construct a `BufferedReader` on top:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: Cannot use this in a static context

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't see the static modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try like this (assuming levels/level.txt is in the jar file):

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("levels/level.txt");
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
   builder.append(line + "\n");
}
```